# Grails refresh-dependencies doesn't download snapshot dependency from local maven repository

Tags: maven, grails, grails-2.1

I am using Grails 2.1.1 and Maven 3.0.3.

In my buildConfig.groovy, I have `pom true` and I generated the pom.xml via `grails create-pom`.  In this pom I have a dependency with `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` which exists only in my local maven repository.  I can successfully run `mvn clean compile` on this pom.

However running `grails refresh-dependencies` does not download the most recent version of my snapshot dependency from my local maven repository.  The only way I can get it to download the latest version is to manually delete it from the ivy cache.

According to the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#changingDependencies):

> All dependencies (jars and plugins) with a version number ending in -SNAPSHOT are implicitly considered to be changing by Grails.

I assume it would recognize my snapshot file as changing and download it when it is modified.  Am I missing some other configuration step?  I only want to use maven for dependency management, but is this entirely the wrong way to use Maven with Grails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't got any responses, what seems like the solution to this is to just not use the grails command line, but rather use the maven goals for Grails.

`mvn grails:run-app` does the trick.  All snapshot dependencies are refreshed and I can start up my app and see the local changes reflected.  This way I'm ignoring ivy altogether and letting maven take care of everything.

**Edit:** If you go this route, I suggest following chapter 5 of the User Guide on [Maven Integration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#antAndMaven) for setting up your pom.xml, etc.  I was able to follow this and get it set up without any surprises.

Answer (score 8):

This is actually the normal behavior of the Aether resolver.

`--refresh-dependencies` doesn't bypass your local maven cache. To do that, you'll need to set the maven repository that contains your dependency to *always* download new snapshots. In BuildConfig.groovy's repositories block:

```
mavenRepo ("http://my.server/repos/my-grails-plugins") {
    updatePolicy 'always'
}
```

Credit to http://asoftwareguy.com/2013/10/25/grails-2-3-maven-dependency-caching-issues/.